# Rails carrierwave and cloudinary multiple file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, cloudinary

So I'm trying to get carrierwave to work with cloudinary for multiple file uploads but it keeps giving me this error that says:

undefined method `all_versions_processors' for Array

I followed the carrierwave documentation where I added a listing_images attribute to my Listings table which is of type json.

I also set the multiple to true option in the form file input.

And in my ListingsController I have specified as one of the permitted params the following:

listing_images: []

I'm pretty sure everything is configured properly but I can't figure out why this error is thrown. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on the road-map to officially support multiple uploads with Carrierwave on Cloudinary's GEM. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can accomplish multiple uploads a bit differently. Here's a basic sample project that demonstrates it:
https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads